# Does this home page design convey trust, calmness and professionalism?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, critique

This is the new home page design for a shopify app development company. Please feel free to share your thoughts, I am here to learn.

The idea is to deliver a better experience and improve conversions.

Does the design convey trust, calmness, professionalism?

[image: Home Page Design]

Comment: Any comments and thoughts on the navigation would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like it. Like others have said, your parameters are a bit vague, so it's difficult to be sure, but it is nicely composed and not cluttered, which gives a sense of calmness, and the CTA at the bottom using stats and real photography gives a sense of professionalism. I like the icons but they feel disjointed with the photo at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is to deliver a better experience and improve conversions.

This cannot be determined from a review of a static image. You will have to test to see how your user base reacts to it.

> Does the design convey trust, calmness, professionalism?

This is a very open ended question. It depends upon your users. The design will appeal to one group of people better than another. I would surmise that it would appeal more to people who sell arts and crafts then professional photographers, designers or people in financial services.

Professionalism and trust in design is not a one-size-fits-all proposition.

Comment: You are right this design is not meant for people in the financial services industry anyways. Thanks for the comments though :)